# Transferred ETH to Metamask

Tags: metamask

I Transferred ETH to Metamask, and shows received, and ok on Etherscan, but not showing under assets. Tried resetting, and transferring to another account, but no results.

Comment: Can you share the transaction hash? Which blockchain were you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the address that received it on Etherscan is the same as your current metamask account, and that metamask is set to Ethereum mainnet.